# If I do a Visa “Run”, can I leave my stuff in that country?

Tags: visa, common-travel-area

Many countries offer 3-6 month stays on a travel visa. If I to do a Visa “run”, am I able to leave my stuff in that country, then later reenter it and come back to the same place I was staying in before?

Comment: Rules related to visa runs are likely to be very country-dependent. You may get better answers if you ask about a specific country.

Comment: The answer might also depend on what you mean by "my stuff."

Comment: Do have a plan for retrieving your property if you are denied entry. See [UK visa refusal, seeking temporary entry to collect personal items](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76471/19560) for an extreme case of a possible problem with leaving stuff behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, yes.  There is no way for a country's authorities to force you to take anything with you when you leave, and they are not usually permitted to confiscate your property under these circumstances.  In fact, they're unlikely to know that you have left anything behind.

However, if you are maintaining a residence in the country, and it is a country that discourages or actively forbids visa runs, then you probably have an increased chance of being refused admission.  It may be unlikely, but some small detail might inspire the immigration officer to suspect that you're residing there and dig a little more deeply.

On the other hand, if you stay away for long enough (a common guideline is to spend no more than half of your time in the country), even a country that discourages visa runs may let you in despite their knowing that you have an apartment there.

Comment: Thanks phoog! Much appreciated